# How to optimize malloc() to get full use of your memory?

Tags: c, memory-management

I wrote a little program to handle word searching the other day and found that, **when keep allocating memory for the *bianry search tree* where I store every one word I tried to analyse, using `malloc()`, my 4G memory would be quickily consumed up.**

There is no memory leek in my program, because I only allocate memory for that binary search tree. But still, I can only allocate less than 6000 binary search trees in my program. The structure of that binary search tree is:

```
typedef struct BSTnode{
    char data[20];
    struct BSTnode* leftchild;    
    struct BSTnode* rightchild;   
    int num;
}BSTnode;
```

So it is pretty small. According to what I have learned, every one of that structure cost 80 bytes of memory(the `data` cost 20 bytes and so is the others because of memory alignment) (right?)

So 6000 that structure in memory would cost 480MB in total.

However, my program failed when I try to allocate memory for that 6000 structrue(It is ok when I allocate memory for *5000* of that).And my PC have 4 GB memory in total!! (with about `1000MB cached`,`2100MB available` and `1100MB free`(according to the task manager on Windows)).

Why is that?

My primary concerns would be:

1. Why is that?
2. How to gracefully manage memory allocation in my program.
3. Could you provide more information?( citation and example and books,etc)

(By the way, if you want to see my code please left a comment below. There is too many lines, it cost some time to make it more readable. sorry)

####################################################################3

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Node
{
  struct Node* leftChild;
  struct Node* rightChild;
  char data[20];
  int num;
} Node;

int inputWord(FILE*, Node*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Enter the name of file you wanna open here:");
  char name[20] =
  { '\0' };
  scanf("%s", name);

  FILE* fs = fopen(name, "r");
  if (!fs)
  {
    perror("Failed to open file!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  Node* firstNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if (firstNode == NULL )
  {
    perror("ALLOCATION FAILED!");
    exit(1);
  }

  firstNode->leftChild = firstNode->rightChild = NULL;
  firstNode->num = 1;
  strcpy(firstNode->data, "a");

  inputWord(fs, firstNode);
  fclose(fs);

  printf("Done!!");
  return 0;
}

int inputWord(FILE* fs, Node* firstNode)
{
  rewind(fs);
  /*first figure out a single word, and then put it into to BST*/
  int flag_1 = 0;
  char buf = '\0';
  char word[20] =
  { '\0' };
  Node* ptrOfNode = firstNode;
  int numOfWord = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    if (numOfWord < 2000)
    {   //amend this number to determine how many word to be input
      if (1 != fread(&buf, 1, 1, fs))
      {
        perror("failed to read file or eof\n");
      }
      if (!isalpha(buf))
        continue;
      /*this while loop is used to picked out a single word in the text*/
      while (flag_1 == 0)
      {
        strncat(word, &buf, 1);
        if (1 != fread(&buf, 1, 1, fs))
        {
          perror("Failed to read char from the file");
          exit(2);
        }
        if (isalpha(buf))
          flag_1 = 0;
        else
          flag_1 = 1;    //now buf is not alpha
      }

      flag_1 = 0;

      while (1)
      {
        if (stricmp(word, ptrOfNode->data) > 0&& ptrOfNode->rightChild!=NULL)
          ptrOfNode = ptrOfNode->rightChild;
        else if (stricmp(word, ptrOfNode->data) < 0 && ptrOfNode->leftChild!=NULL)               
          ptrOfNode = ptrOfNode->leftChild;
        else
          break;
      }
   /*the while loop above break for only two reason:
    *1.there have been an identical word in the tree;
    *2.the child where I want to insert the word have not been allocated memory
    */
      if (stricmp(word, ptrOfNode->data) == 0)
      {
        ++(ptrOfNode->num);
        memset(word, '\0', 20);
        ptrOfNode = firstNode;  //move the pointer of Node to the very first
        numOfWord+=1;
        continue;
      }
      else
      {
        if (stricmp(word, ptrOfNode->data) > 0)
        {        //mean that there is no more right child
          ptrOfNode->rightChild = malloc(sizeof(Node));
          if (ptrOfNode->rightChild == NULL )
          {
            perror("FAILED TO ALLOCATED MEMORY!!");
            exit(1);
          }
          ptrOfNode = ptrOfNode->rightChild;
          ptrOfNode->leftChild = ptrOfNode->rightChild = NULL;
          ptrOfNode->num = 1;
          strcpy(ptrOfNode->data, word);

          memset(word, '\0', 20);
          ptrOfNode = firstNode;
          numOfWord += 1;
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          ptrOfNode->leftChild = malloc(sizeof(Node));
          if (ptrOfNode->leftChild == NULL )
          {
            perror("FAILED TO ALLOCATE MEMORY!");
            exit(1);
          }
          ptrOfNode = ptrOfNode->leftChild;
          ptrOfNode->leftChild = ptrOfNode->rightChild = NULL;
          ptrOfNode->num = 1;
          strcpy(ptrOfNode->data, word);

          memset(word, '\0', 20);
          ptrOfNode = firstNode;
          numOfWord += 1;
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    else
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And there is another program I wrote which can absolutely explained my question. But it is way too long that I can't make it readable for all of you and post it here.[1]https://github.com/walkerlala/searchText

If you don't think this is a proper program for this question(the one in my link would absolutely be), please **consider about my concerns above**.

Comment: Reordering the struct members and/or using `#pragma pack` can save some bytes, which multiplied by `6000` would become a lot.

Comment: First of all you have to remember that you are not alone on your system, there are other processes using memory as well. Also remember that memory can become fragmented, and if no fragment is big enough for your structure the allocation will fail. Furthermore, the operating system needs to keep track of your allocations (and other resources) so the allocations might use more memory than just plain `sizeof(BSTNode)`

Comment: And can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? It should include *how* you detect that you can't allocate more memory, but first and foremost how you allocate memory now (i.e one big array? each node for itself? chunks of nodes?)

Comment: Are you allocating your `BSTnode` structures individually, or are you allocating them a bunch at a time?  Are you dynamically allocating memory for anything else in the same program?  Are you calling `realloc` a lot? There are some simple, obvious memory allocation patterns which can end up maximizing the fragmentation of memory and maximizing the probability that one of your `malloc` requests will fail even though you "still have plenty of memory left".

Comment: Also, 480MB is way more than what's required for the 6000 structs, so I doubt that your system is failing because of the lack of enough memory or because of what @JoachimPileborg explained in his first comment.

Comment: please wait a minute I would post my code

Comment: 6000 x 80 bytes = 480000 bytes = 469 KB = 0.46 MB so I'm pretty sure you have a bug in your code.

Comment: I have a virtual machine with only 512 M of memory. I could allocated without error 10000 blocs of 256 bytes because it is only around 2.5 MB !

Comment: and it's not 80bytes at all, on a 64bit machine it would be 48bytes with padding 40bytes without padding, which can be achieved by movnig the first member to the end of the struct.

Comment: and is it a 32 bit or 64 bit program? 32 bit programs have rather less usable memory than 64 bit programs

Comment: why is it 80 bytes. isn't it 32 bytes?

Comment: @alk I use this to put a char into `word`. you see, i read char by char from the stream and then put them one by one into `word`. When a single word is read, the `while` loop would break and the program would put that word into the BST

Comment: @alk But I set the `n` to be only 1, which mean that no matter what is behind behind that piece of memory, it is the same. That is, only that char count

Comment: Fair enough, my bad, ignored the `n`. Sry.

Comment: `strncat(word, &buf, 1);` does not look good. And reading one character at a time using fread() doesn't either)

Comment: bug fixed. thanks for all of your review and suggestions

Comment: Is your solution interesting enough to post as an answer? Does it answer your 3 enumerated questions?

Comment: @Jongware Actually, not so interesting. I just fixed the bug. sure it answer two of my question. But I myself cannot say I can now "gracefully manage memory allocation"

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some simple code to simulate your problem.

```
struct Node{
    int val;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node() :val(1){}
};

int main(){
    int size = sizeof(Node);//size = 12Bytes
    const int N = 10e5;
    const int factor = 5;//12B*5*10^5 = 6MB
    Node* ptrArr[factor];
    //Test 1, costs 57MB!
    for (int i = 0; i < factor; i++){
        ptrArr[i] = new Node[N];
    }
    //Test 2, costs 348MB!
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < N*factor; i++){
        Node *temp = new Node;
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

We want to allocate `5*10e5` * `Node`s, and in theory, it will costs `12Bytes * 5 * 10e5 = 6MB`.

I run this code in `VS2013`, and `Test 1` costs `57MB` while `Test 2`costs `348MB`!

So back to your question, why is that?

1. One reason is **fragment**, another reason is reserved memory.

   - If you open `DEBUG->WINDOWS->MEMORY` and look at the address of `ptrArr[i]`, you will find that after those memory used to save `Node`, there is quite a big area of unused memory.
   - For example, `ptrArr[0] = 0x00b18040` and `ptrArr[1] = 0x0169f040`. `0x0169f040 - 0x00b18040 = 0xb87000 = 12087296 Bytes ≈ 12*10e6 Bytes`
   - So, Visual Studio allocates 10 times memory than we need.
   - What about `Test 2`? Smaller memory allocated at a single time, more memory fragments.
2. How to gracefully manage memory allocation in my program?

   - Avoid frequent allocating small pieces of memory.*(It's quite slow and costs more memory.)*
3. More information.

   - Do you know how `std::vector` increase in Visual Studio?
   - `std::vector<int> numbers;` When we push one number a time, the capacity of `numbers` will change like this:
   - `1->2->3->4->6->9->13->19->...->n->(n+n/2)->...`
   - I think it's similar to this question: reserve extra space, avoid frequent reallocate operation, increase efficiency.(I'm not very sure about it.)
   - If you want to know more about memory management in OS, you can read *Modern Operation System (Tanenbaum)* Chapter 3.